# How can I get player names in Game Center multiplayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c

As the title says I wondering how you can show both the local players alias and the other GKplayers alias. I'm using this Game Center manager i found on the internet  https://github.com/nihalahmed/GameCenterManager. However I can only find a method for displaying the local players alias.

```
- (NSString *)localPlayerDisplayName {
    if ([self isGameCenterAvailable] && [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated) {
        if ([[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayName)]) {
            return [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].displayName;
        } else {
            return [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].alias;
        }
    }

    return @"unknownPlayer";
}
```

How can possibly find the other GKPlayers alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask Game Center for a player (or players) based on something like their identifiers (or a list of friends, or various other items). From there, you can get the alias and other information just like you do for the local player.

Here's skeleton code from the Game Center documentation, for example:

```
- (void) loadPlayerData: (NSArray *) identifiers
{
    [GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:identifiers withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *players, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil)
        {
            // Handle the error.
        }
        if (players != nil)
        {
            // Process the array of GKPlayer objects.
        }
     }];
}
```

If you need help on creating the array of players to begin with, you can get that by asking for the player's friends list, or the currently-connected player, or various other ways.

Comment: Found another solution on RayWenderlich.com by using the GKMatch to get an array of the players